# What could be the cause of this page load latency?

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, google-cloud-platform, https

I have an app written in golang that runs on Google App Engine. I've added a redis caching layer so that database requests are fast. I've confirmed through logs that once the request comes in, the request completes extremely quickly:

[image: golang latency]

You can see here redis was hit twice during the request and the whole request took only 3.44ms. And yet... the actual request as reported by Chrome/Firefox took over 50ms:

[image: firefox latency report]

Where could this other 51ms of latency be coming from? Is this expected? I initially thought "HTTPS", but firefox reports connecting and tls setup costs as 0 ms. Is this all just network latency since I'm in Maryland and the app is in us-central1? Or is there some other explanation for the extra 51 ms?

Comment: You will definitely have network latency. If your page is only taking 56 milliseconds to load, that is very fast.

Comment: This [reference](https://www.bluecorona.com/blog/how-fast-should-website-be/) might also help.